# Hibernate: How can I register POJO classes dynamically at runtime?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create POJO classes dynamically at runtime and map them to Hibernate. However, I am failing at the second part.

After I generate the class file, I am placing it in a location that Hibernate scans for POJOs. But it's not working.

I have tried rebuilding session factory again, so that it may pick up the newly created file but that's not working. Also rebuilding session factory can't be a good/scalable solution.

Hibernate setup code:

```java
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder =
                new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder.scanPackages("com.aasaan.cp.dbo").scanPackages("com.aasaan.cp.dynaclass")
                .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
```

Error:

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: test_component is not mapped [SELECT Test AS Test from test_component]
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that there is not mapped type called **test_component**. You have to use the names of the types, not the tables.

If the code is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_component")
public class Test
```

So you have to use **Test** rather than **test_component**